# Best approach to avoid repetitive database connection in Object Oriented Programming

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, data-structures

Here is the sample code in Python.

[sample.py]

```
class MyApp(object):
     
      def __init__(self):
         self.instance = None

         self.connect()


    def connect(self):
        if self.instance is None:
            print('Connecting to DB...')
            self.instance = 1 # Assume connected
        return self.instance
```

[A.py]

```
from sample import MyApp
from B import again

a = MyApp()
again()
```

[B.py]

```
from sample import MyApp

def again():
    b = MyApp()
```

Wouldn't like to call the `connect()` method explicitly by `MyApp().connect()`, so that added in `__init__` method itsef. (Please do advice if any better approach is available, Is `__new__()` will be helpful in this context?)

**[Output]**

```
>> python A.py
Connecting to DB...
Connecting to DB...
```

**[Expected]**

```
>> python A.py
Connecting to DB...
```

I don't want to create an instance again and again. Any suggestion/advise would be grateful. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `self.instance` is on the *instance*. What you want is to put that as a class attribute so that all the instances have that info. To access it, use `self.__class__.instance`. Also, in Python3, classes don't need to inherit from `object`.

```py
>>> class MyApp:
...     instance = None
...
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.connect()
...
...     def connect(self):
...         if self.__class__.instance is None:
...             print('connecting')
...             self.__class__.instance = 1
...
>>>
>>> a = MyApp()  # will connect the first time
connecting
>>> b = MyApp()  # no new connection
>>> a.connect()  # no new connection
>>> b.connect()  # no new connection
```

(Btw, in this case especially, `instance` is not a good name, since it's the exact opposite. Use `connected` = `True`/`False` instead.)

And if `connect()` doesn't need access to other instance variables, it can be a `classmethod` and use `cls.instance`:

```py
>>> class ... # as before
...     @classmethod
...     def connect(cls):  # cls is the class
...         if cls.instance is None:
...             print('connecting')
...             cls.instance = 1
```